# Python pickling returning a string when I've pickled a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I'm currently learning about pickling in Python and I'm confused with an error I'm getting complaing that the unpickled variable I'm initalizing does not have a particular attribute I'm wanting to use.

I'm pickling a dictionary of the script's data and then trying to *unpickle.load* it back using the following code:

```
def loadData():
    global script_data_filepath
    with open(script_data_filepath) as script_data_file:
        data_to_load = pickle.load(script_data_file)
        for data_item in data_to_load.items():
            print(data_item[0])
            print(data_item[1])
```

The problem is that Python is saying that *items()* is not an attribute of data_to_load because data_to_load is of type '*str*'. In the code I've given this is the first time that data_to_load is declared, I pressumed that it would dynamically take whatever type is assigned to it (which should be a dictionary as that's what I know will be loaded from this file).

Comment: Since the problem isn't in the code you've pasted (if this code gives an error, what was pickled *was* a string), can you add the code where you pickle the data? Have you tried to pickle and unpickle to/from a string as a test? Also pickle to `protocol=0`, and inspect if the correct object is pickled.

Comment: Random advice: If you want to store data use shelve or a db (ie sqlite). Pickle works only in the most trivial cases.

Comment: Interesting - I've literally never run into issues with Pickle. And you do know that shelve is just a wrapper around pickle, right?

Comment: Hey guys - sorry it turns out I was doing something really stupid. I hadn't yet saved using my NEW saving mechanism using the dictionary (I was still just saving a string). It works very well now. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work. The code you posted is fine. How are you dumping it? You're using `pickle.dump`, not `pickle.dumps` for a string? Your problem is almost certainly in the dumping code.

```
>>> import cPickle
>>> foo = {4:2}
>>> cPickle.dump(foo, open('foo.pickle', 'wb'))
>>> data_to_load = cPickle.load(open('foo.pickle'))
>>> data_to_load.items()
[(4, 2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I figured out that I was doing something stupid and hadn't yet used my new saving method (that saves a dictionary) and so I really was loading in a string. Thanks for the help.